# Reading and writing the same (depth) attachment in a subpass

Tags: vulkan

I am trying to use light volumes for my deferred renderer. But i come across a problem with stencil operations.
Right now i am using a depth/stencil attachment with format `VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT_S8_UINT`. In the lighting subpass i need to read the depth to reconstruct position, and read and write the stencil to mask the light volume.
To the lighting subpass I want to add the depth/stencil as an input attachment, and as a depth attachment, but these require different layout which are obviously not possible at the same time.

Right now i am referring to the same attachment both as an input attachment and a depth attachment in the same subpass.
As input attachment the layout is `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` and as depth attachment the layout is `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL` (giving no validation errors?), and my stencil operations are not executed.

Now i could create two different attachments for depth and stencil, but that would possibly use more memory, which is not great either. So my question is, how do you setup a subpass where you can read and write the same depth/stencil attachment? (within a single pipeline as well)

Comment: you should be able to use the layout GENERAL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but these require different layout

Nonsense; that's what the `GENERAL` layout is for. The specification even explicitly brings that up:

> An attachment used as both an input attachment and depth/stencil attachment must be in either the VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL or VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL layout

Obviously the latter is not helpful for you ;)